# Metamask false positive error: ERC20 transferFrom tx displays "Exception thrown" error in metamask, but tx confirms fine

Tags: web3js, erc-20, metamask

I'm fairly certainly this is due to approvals- that metamask thinks that an error will be thrown because the contract does not have approval to transfer the ERC20- *even though the approval tx is currently pending*.

My dapp, just like other Dapps, when it needs to get Dai from a user first asks the user to approve the transfer, then there is a second tx where the actual transfer is made. Of course, by the time the second tx has appeared, the approval transaction has not yet confirmed, so metamask thinks it will fail. But, it doesn't, because the approval tx has a lower nonce so will always confirm first.

I don't see other dapps with this problem, any idea what I'm doing wrong? Why can metamask usually take into account a pending tx when trying to figure out if a new tx will fail, but in my case it can't?

See it for yourself, my dapp is public, on kovan. You will need kovan ETH. Please visit harber.io and click on any team. Then press 'Get $100 Test Dai' and wait until confirmed. Then select a rental price and deposit (rental price must be higher than whatever it currently is, deposit must be less than 100) and press 'rent token'. You will see two transactions, the first is the approval for the exact amount of the transfer, and the second is to transfer the Dai. The second transaction, before pressing submit, has the error:

'ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.'

But go ahead and submit it, it will work fine.

The front end code which is initiating the two transactions is [here](https://github.com/mcplums/HarberFrontEnd/blob/master/src/components/TokenPage/BuyForm.js#L64).

For reference, here are the two relevant txs on etherscan:

The approval tx: https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x4b80ed0fcf21bcb369a2d60b0ffcbb1677ea61e3ff758b37a696e5fe14cd5786

The transferFrom tx (called via my contract): https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xe4e4b79425c9d639dea20e67ca761d4ca34509380a45920f0f593ee806a60aaf

Both confirm just fine with zero errors. Yet for the second tx, metamask reported said the tx would throw.

Comment: Your link isn't very helpful. Please share a link to the transaction on Etherscan.

Comment: Sorry if stupid question- but how will that help, if there is no error on the tx? It is just two normal txs, one of them calling approve, and one of them calling transferFrom, both of which confirm just fine. The error is a display error on metamask only.

Comment: A reverted transaction is registered on the blockchain (how else would you know that it has been reverted? A miner must execute it). I would like to see if your transaction has been reverted (in opposed to what you may think).

Comment: Ok sure, updated the main post with the links.

Comment: Huh! The destination addresses (`to`) of these transactions are two different contracts. What exactly is the point in `approve` on contract A and then `transferFrom` on contract B???

Comment: I dont understand? They are to two different contracts because the first is to the Dai contract directly, approving my contract. The second is to my contract to do X, and then my contract calls transferFrom as part of X. You can see that the first tx approves the address of my contract.

Comment: BTW, `transferFrom` may fail not only as a result of not calling `approve`, but also as a result of insufficient balance.

Comment: Ok sure, but it isn't failing in this instance. To be clear: the problem I'm having is that metamask THINKS the transaction will fail, even though it doesnt. The problem is not that my transactions are failing.

Comment: Yes, but when A approves B to transfer tokens on its behalf, the approval is made on a token contract, i.e., `token.approve(B, amount, {from: A})`. Then the transfer itself is made on **the same** token contract, i.e., `token.transferFrom(B, C, amount, {from: A})`.

Comment: So I guess that metamask runs it in a sandbox (i.e., calls `token.transferFrom(B, C, amount).estimateGas({from: A})`), and finds out that it will fail.

Comment: Have you possibly called `approve` on that other token contract (the one which you end up calling `transferFrom` on), with a very large value?

Comment: Sure, the transfer is made on the same token? It's just made via my contract, not directly, in the second tx which is why the to: address is different. But both transactions refer to the token at address 0x86309723166c177591960e5a9a5ecb7056564331.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106666/discussion-between-andrew-stanger-and-goodvibration).

Comment: Let me know if you'd rather not use the chat and I will answer your other queries here :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :) it turns out that I'm an idiot.

When I said in the OP "I don't see other dapps with this problem, any idea what I'm doing wrong?"

It turns out that other dapps DO have this problem, so they always wait for the first tx to confirm before doing the second tx. My memory was different, but wrong.